# Extjs 4.2 autosync dynamic grid store

Tags: javascript, php, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a grid with dynamic columns:

**MODEL**

```
Ext.define('App.mdlCriteriosConcurso', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
    ]   
});
```

**STORE**

```
Ext.define('App.strCriteriosConcurso', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model:  'App.mdlCriteriosConcurso',
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax', 
        api: {
            read: 'some url',
            update: 'some url',
        },
        reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data',
                totalProperty: 'total'
        },
        writer: {
            root: 'records',
            encode: true,
            writeAllFields: true
        }
    }
});
```

**GRID**

```
var almacenCriteriosConcurso = Ext.create('App.strCriteriosConcurso');
//Some code ...
{
    xtype:'grid',
    itemId:'gridCriteriosConcursoV4',
    store:almacenCriteriosConcurso,
    plugins: [Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {clicksToEdit: 2})],
    columns:[]
}
//Some code...
```

**CONTROLLER**

Here in the controller I have the next piece of code:

```
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('viewFichaDetalle #tabpanelsecundario4_1 #gridCriteriosConcursoV4')[0].getStore().addListener('metachange',function(store,meta){
        var columnas=0;
        var renderer1 = function(v,params,data){
            if(v==''){
                return '<div style="background-color:#F5FAC3;color:blue;">'+Ext.util.Format.number(0,'0.000,00/i')+'</div>';
            }
            else{
                return '<div style="background-color:#F5FAC3;color:blue;">'+Ext.util.Format.number(v,'0.000,00/i')+'</div>';
            }
        };
        var renderer2 = function(v,params,data){
            if(v=='' || v==0){
                return '<div style="background-color:#F5FAC3;color:green;">'+Ext.util.Format.number(0,'0.000,00/i')+'</div>';
                //return '';
            }
            else{
                return '<div style="background-color:#F5FAC3;color:green;">'+Ext.util.Format.number(v,'0.000,00/i')+'</div>';
            }
        };

        Ext.each(meta.columns,function(col){
            if(columnas==2){
                meta.columns[columnas].renderer = renderer1;
            }
            if(columnas>=3){
                meta.columns[columnas].renderer = renderer2;
            }
            columnas++;
        },this);
        Ext.suspendLayouts();
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('viewFichaDetalle #tabpanelsecundario4_1 #gridCriteriosConcursoV4')[0].reconfigure(store, meta.columns);
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('viewFichaDetalle #tabpanelsecundario4_1 #gridCriteriosConcursoV4')[0].setTitle("<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size: 12pt'>Criterios del Concurso con ID:</span> "+"<span style='color:black;font-weight:bold;font-size: 12pt'>"+this.IdConcurso+"</span>");
        Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
    },this);
```

I create the columns in the php, using the metadata.

With this code I add some renderers to the grid columns. And I see all the data perfect, and can edit the data.

In the php y generate the column and the field like this:

```
$array_metadata['columns'][]=array("header"=>"<span style='color:blue;'>Resultado</span>","dataIndex"=>"puntos_resultado","width"=>82,"align"=>"right","editor"=>"textfield");
$array_metadata['fields'][]=array("name"=>"puntos_resultado","type"=>"float");
```

And then pass $array_metadata to 'metaData' response.

But when I try to sync or autosync the store I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at constructor.getRecordData (ext-all-dev.js:62247)
    at constructor.write (ext-all-dev.js:62192)
    at constructor.doRequest (ext-all-dev.js:102306)
    at constructor.update (ext-all-dev.js:101753)
    at constructor.runOperation (ext-all-dev.js:106842)
    at constructor.start (ext-all-dev.js:106769)
    at constructor.batch (ext-all-dev.js:62869)
    at constructor.sync (ext-all-dev.js:64066)
    at constructor.afterEdit (ext-all-dev.js:64162)
    at constructor.callStore (ext-all-dev.js:101428)
```

**UPDATE 1**

I have fount this thread in Sencha Forums [link](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?131583-OPEN-EXTJSIV-1789-4-0-0-Cannot-edit-cells-after-grid-reconfigure) , and I have tried all posibles solutions and Im getting allways the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells us that you don't fill the model's `fields` array properly, because that is where `name` is a required config. In ExtJS 4, you have to add all fields to the model for the sync to work properly.

To be exact, the Model prototype has to be filled with the correct fields before the instances are created.

This means that you will have to override the reader's [`getResponseData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Json2.html#Ext-data-reader-Json-method-getResponseData) method, because between `Ext.decode` and `readRecords` you will have to prepare the model prototype by setting the fields as returned from the server; something like this:

```
App.mdlCriteriosConcurso.prototype.fields = data.fields;
```

Comment: I will try this solution